# Do we believe in fairytales that are not scientific?

Tags: allah, history, belief, miracles, mythology

I read a question before about myths and it basically asked about fairytales or something along the lines of that but the answers werent good enough.
Normally, when talking to non-Muslims but mainly atheists they usually make jokes out of things like the prophets split the sea and I know this isnt from the Quran but the example of turning wine into water. Things like that. They say we believe in fairytales that arent true.
If I think about it fairly and from both sides it does seem understandable that many atheists would think like this. In the question I read it said something like Muslims have records for the actions but that only shows the Muslim side and not other sides. The question is about greeks but I am talking about stories in general.
Why is believing in these things seen as so ridiculous? Why do we believe in these things when they defy physics and things like that? Saying that God can do whatever doesnt really make it true or set the argument because then in that case all the Gods of the other religions could have power to do the actions and they could change science so the miracle could happen.
Also in the question it says that evidence of miracles like this havent come up recently and that is kind of true. We havent seen things like moons splitting etc and now that science is developing we understand the effects it will have on the Earth too.
Is the belief in these stories/fairytales ridiculous and not scientific/logical?

Comment: If you don't believe in the qur'an as a whole you can't safely call yourself a Muslim. Further before claiming the stories in the qur'an as fairytale you should quote those you are regarding as such. I don't know of any that have no historical backup nor any that can be regarded as myths or fairytale at all. Further even science is not exact if you leave maths aside, even physics partly rely on not yet proven mathematical assumptions. And finally belief is a matter of heart first and mind secondly. The qur'an often uses examples that were understandable for the people of the time.

Comment: Can u please give evidence for your claim about Maths and Physics. Also Im talking about the stories like splitting of the ocean, Ive seen the moon splitting being interpreted as an eclipse but I dont know how it is possible for the splitting of the ocean. Also I didnt say I dont believe in the Quran as a whole I just find it hard to believe in certain things. Like the other user said in the question, there are more ways to record things like online etc now and even during the prophets time there were more ways and suddenly the miracles stopped or are more natural/normal if u know what i mean

Comment: Miracles are related to prophets its normal that they've stopped. Well I'm not much into physics myself, but I recall in my studies on functional analysis or complex analysis (I just recall the teacher not the actual topic). The teacher told us that in maths this theory is not yet proven however in physics they assume it to be so and built a theory on it.

Comment: But if they assumed doesnt mean that it isnt logical, even though the miracles are related to the prophets others saw them and that even adds on to a question like how is life a test if you seen miracles and know god exists.

Comment: Something unproven remains uncertain and therefore could be right but also wrong. Assumption is not certainty, but a kind of doubt. And the qur'an teaches us to search certainty. Note that the more you have doubt on the qur'an the more you get doubt about your own faith. Most of the stories in the qur'an can be resumed, as Allah gave people guidance (by Prophets, or revelation such as the qur'an), but there's also temptation and those who are not able to fight the latter will fail in the hereafter. Anything else might be a detail th shouldn't bother us.

Comment: But even if there is temptation the people witnessed God splitting an ocean that to me at least seems to ruin the whole idea of a test. It also just doesnt sound logical to me, especially when now you can write the stories online and it can be recorded with evidence even during the prophets time you could write it in quite a lot of places so the miracles of the prophet have been interpreted. However, back up to like Musa or even further back all these miracles are so extraordinary but arent interpeted in different ways. I also dont see the historical evidence.

Comment: A sea is not an ocean and the specific Pharao is displayed in the Egyptian Museum in Cairo. Honestly I regard it a waste of time to discuss this topic as it seems you insist discussing useless points.

Comment: People have actually identified the pharaoh as potentially a different pharaoh but regardless it still doesnt mean that it is logical or natural. Also please can you answer the thing I wrote about how now theres more evidence and ways to record evidence but back then...

Answer (score 3):

That all depends on whether you choose to put your faith in Allah or in the Scientific Method.

The Scientific Method is a great tool for understanding the universe and all of Creation, but it is limited in that it can only apply to things that can be observed. It is useless for understanding *al-ghaib*.

Allah, on the other hand, has no such limitations. He is not bound by physics, by the constraints of His own creation: Everything is within His power, no matter how "ridiculous" it may seem to others.

> Originator of the heavens and the earth. When He decrees a matter, He only says to it, "Be," and it is.
>   <sup>—[Al-Baqarah 117](https://legacy.quran.com/2/117)</sup>

Comment: I understand that Allah knows and can do whatever but still the whole reason we believe in these is because we accept the Quran to be true. Numerous people do not and so lots of these stories are just seen as ancient fairytales. The point of how they defy physics etc stll remain and the fact that no miracles are happening as we learn about how splitting the ocean etc could affect others and science develops. Also, life is supposed to be a test but these stories show the people involved that God does exist so then it basically ruins the whole point of the test.

Comment: can you show how it is limited. Also why is it that when the sea was split there is barely any evidence but now that there are numerous different ways to write it online or record it or even during the prophets time when there were quite a lot of ways to record it there arent any miracles happening or they are being interpreted e.g the splitting of the moon was seen as an eclispe